# ASP.NET Core OpenIdConnect id_token FrontChannel Logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, asp.net-core-identity

I am using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` .NET 8 libraries for authentication for an on-premise AD FS (Application Group / NativeClientApplication).

So far, the authentication and the logout directly from the application are working without any trouble.

I have issues with the front channel logout as described here:

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html#rfc.section.3.1

So I sign in, in my OAuth application "A", then I switch to another application "B", without the need to sign in again, because of SSO. When hitting sign-out in application "B", ADFS starts to call clean up calls for all applications where an SSO was granted.

I can also see the requests from ADFS to my application A. Afterwards I am again on the sign in page of ADFS, *but* when navigating back to application A directly, I am still signed in, because the cookies in application A were not terminated for the front channel process (I also checked if there is an issue with the SameSite settings of the cookie, no problem here).

Here the sign out signal from ADFS to application A:

[image: FrontChannelLogout]

And the callback:

[image: Callback]

The working direct logout looks like this:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = new Uri($"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Request.PathBase}").ToString() }
        );
```

This is my configuration set up:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(configureOptions =>
{
    configureOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    configureOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(configureOptions =>
{
    configureOptions.SlidingExpiration = true;

}).AddOpenIdConnect(configureOptions =>
{
    configureOptions.SaveTokens = true;
    configureOptions.MetadataAddress = "https://my.idp.com/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    configureOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    configureOptions.SignOutScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    configureOptions.Scope.Clear();
    configureOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
    configureOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    configureOptions.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-oidc";
    configureOptions.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc";
    configureOptions.ClientId = "https://example.com/applications/oauthpassive/";
});
```

I created a functional breakpoint in the method `HandleRemoteSignOutAsync` in the class `OpenIdConnectHandler`:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs

So when the front channel logout from the IdP is triggerd, I can see also in the network panel, that the request is pending, because of the breakpoint:
[image: Break in callback]

When debugging, I see that the code is executed and it is not breaking somewhere between:
[image: Debug]

Nevertheless, the user is still logged in the application A.
Any ideas what I could configure, develop or investigate?

## Workaround

After some more investigation I found a workaround to get rid of the authentication cookies when the front channel logout is received:

```
configureOptions.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnRemoteSignOut = async context =>
    {
        await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
};
```

Still wondering if there is a built-in solution for this kind of sign out.